# How to resolve Uri parameter in another page using MVVMLight page in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I met a question when using MVVMLight in WP7. When create a message and navigate to another page in ViewModel like following below:

```
 var msg = new GoToPageMessage() { PageName = "Page2", Params="Index=1" };
 Messenger.Default.Send<GoToPageMessage>( msg );
```

In MainPage.xaml, I register it:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<GoToPageMessage>( this, ( action ) => ReceiveMessage( action ) );
```

And the ReceiveMessge as following below:

```
  private object ReceiveMessage( GoToPageMessage action )
  {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "/Views/" );
     sb.Append( action.PageName );
     sb.Append( ".xaml" );
     NavigationService.Navigate(
        new System.Uri( sb.ToString()+"?"+action.Params, System.UriKind.Relative ) );
     return null;
  }
```

I want to know how to solve the action.Params in the next page. I don`t want to write them to xxx.xaml.cs. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `OnNavigatedTo` event on the other pages, you can query the parameters via `NavigationContext.QueryString.Keys`